# Ubuntu releases and package backports

Tags: ubuntu, security

I was looking at the [PHP EOL schedule](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) today and noticed the version that ships with Ubuntu 16.04 (PHP 7.0) is shown as no longer supported on php.net. I'm wondering then, if Ubuntu [does backporting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) of security fixes, where are the patches for something like PHP 7.0 coming from since it's unsupported on php.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're coming from the same place newer versions come from. Part of the duties of someone maintaining an out-of-support release for a long-term-support distribution is learning how to take a patch that applies to a newer version and figuring out how to apply it to an older one. Sometimes there are whole communities for this, though I'm not sure if PHP is one of them. It takes software engineering know-how, and, frankly, getting paid to do it.